# different encrypted versions on encrypting the same string using the same key

Tags: python, pycrypto

This is simply driving me crazy.

This is what happenned:

Inside the python shell:

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4
>>> a = ARC4.new('0123456789123456')
>>> b = ARC4.new('0123456789123456')
>>> de = b.decrypt
>>> en = a.encrypt
>>> en('abcd')
'\x18\x07\x8a\xdc'
>>> en('abcd')
'\x89>\xa0T'
>>> en('abcd')
'y\xe1-\xfe'
>>> en('abcd')
'\xc7\xf6\x19\xfc'
>>>
```

I encrypted `abcd` 4 times with the same key. And all the four times I got different encrypted strings.

And when I did the following thing(Maybe I would get the same decrypted message on decrypting all the above different encrypted messages).

```
>>> al  = []
>>> for i in range(10):
    al.append(en('abcd'))


>>> al
['\x81\x05h\x06', '\x11;\x88\xc7', '\xb6\xb9g\x10', '\x1e$\x8c\xca', '\xbdh\xc2\xf0', 'ruiO', '7\xec\x7f\xdf', '\x08\xf3\x90\x8a', '\x1c\x95\xf3(', '\xbd@-\x11']

>>> gl = []
>>> for i in range(10):
    gl.append(de(al[i]))


>>> gl
['\xc8\x0f6\xb7', '\x18y`A', 'tm\x12\t', '\x9c\xf65M', '\xd6\xe8\x02\xa3', 'M\xa5sc', '\x1b\x82|\x08', '\x87\xbd \xd7', '\xd3:f\xd7', '\x05\x81?\xc5']
>>>
```

So not even once did I get the original message `abcd`..!

Why is this happening??

How do I overcome this??

**Please** help me solve this issue.

I am using the pyCrypto library on a Linux Mint machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ACR4 is a stream cipher. It does not encrypt the way you think it does. Try this:

```
en("abcd" * 16)
```

and see what happens. The result will *not* be 16 times the same bytes but similar to what you tried in your question.

If you want to encrypt to the *same* bytes, you must use a *new instance* of ACR4:

```
e1 = ACR4.new('0123456789123456').encrypt
e2 = ACR4.new('0123456789123456').encrypt

assert e1("abcd") == e2("abcd")
```

Answer (score 3):

RC4 is a stream cipher, so the encrypted form of some plaintext depends on what the cipher has already encrypted.

```
>>> encrypted = [en('abcd') for i in range(4)]
>>> encrypted
['(h=\xd5', 'h \x8b\xe2', '\xa3\xb6\x16}', '\xe3\xb0\xda\xe3']
>>> decrypted = [de(x) for x in encrypted]
>>> decrypted
['abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd']
```

Create new RC4 objects before doing the encryption/decryption and you'll get the result you expect:

```
>>> a = ARC4.new('0123456789123456')
>>> b = ARC4.new('0123456789123456')
>>> de = b.decrypt
>>> en = a.encrypt
>>> al  = []
>>> for i in range(10):
...   al.append(en('abcd'))
... 
>>> gl = []
>>> for i in range(10):
...   gl.append(de(al[i]))
... 
>>> gl
['abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd']
```